# How to capture mouse right click paste function in Winforms

Tags: vb.net, winforms, mouseevent, paste

I would like to know how to capture right click and paste option through mouse click.
It is a winforms application. I would be modifying the contents of clipboard before pasting.
I am able to perform this through ctrl+V but not able to find a way to handle mouse right click.

I have tried this so far:

```
   Private Const WM_PASTE As Integer = &H302
   Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef msg As Message)
        If msg.Msg = WM_PASTE AndAlso Clipboard.ContainsText() Then
            Clipboard.SetText(Clipboard.GetText().Replace(vbCrLf, " "))
        End If
        MyBase.WndProc(msg)
    End Sub
```

Comment: This code should work fine. Maybe you have overriden WndProc in the wrong control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this to be working like awesome:

```
    <System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
    Private Shared Function FindWindowEx(hwndParent As IntPtr, hwndChildAfter As IntPtr, lpszClass As String, lpszWindow As String) As IntPtr
    End Function

    Private Sub SearchCriteria_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles SearchCriteria.MouseDown
        Dim lhWnd As IntPtr = FindWindowEx(SearchCriteria.Handle, IntPtr.Zero, "EDIT", Nothing)
        If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right And lhWnd <> 0 Then
            Clipboard.SetText(Clipboard.GetText().Replace(vbCrLf, " "))
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Note that since this approach just looks for a mouse click, it does not work when the context menu is openend by the keyboard so you still can paste in text that does not get changed.

Answer (score 2):

You have to process the `WM_PASTE` windows message using [`WndProc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.control.wndproc.aspx) (a list of all messages can be found [here](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Constants/WM.html)).

For example, this `TextBox` will print all text pasted into it (no matter how) to the console instead of displaying it itself:

```
Class CapturePasteBox
    Inherits TextBox

    Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As Message)
        If m.Msg = &H302 AndAlso Clipboard.ContainsText() Then
            Dim text = Clipboard.GetText()
            '' do something with text
            Console.WriteLine(text)
            Return '' return so the text won't be pasted into the TextBox
        End If
        MyBase.WndProc(m)
    End Sub
End Class
```

---

In response to your comment:

The `ComboBox`-control needs some [special treatment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649028%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), since

> When sent to a combo box, the WM_PASTE message is handled by its edit control.

So you can use the following function/class using a [`NativeWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.nativewindow.aspx):

```
<System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError := True)> _
Private Shared Function FindWindowEx(hwndParent As IntPtr, hwndChildAfter As IntPtr, lpszClass As String, lpszWindow As String) As IntPtr
End Function

Public Class PasteHandler
Inherits NativeWindow
    Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As Message)
    If m.Msg = &H302 Then
        Clipboard.SetText(ClipBoard.GetText().Replace("e", "XXX"))
    End If

    MyBase.WndProc(m)
    End Sub
End Class
```

and use it with your `ComboBox`:

```
'' Get the edit control of the combobox
Dim lhWnd As IntPtr = FindWindowEx(yourComboBox.Handle, IntPtr.Zero, "EDIT", Nothing)

'' assign the edit control to the Pastehandler
Dim p As New PasteHandler()
p.AssignHandle(lhWnd)
```

Comment: Yes. I tried the same earlier too but it doesn't seem to work for mouse rt clicks. I have updated my question with what i have tried so far.

Comment: @anony It generally works for every kind of pasting. Would you mind share the code you tried?

Comment: @anony In which class have you overriden `WndProc`? Are you sure it's the control you paste the text in?

Comment: And this is supposed to be done after form initialization rt? I am opening a new form when a link a clicked. So i am not able to apply this for my child form. In parent form i donot need this so i am not able to see the functionality.

Comment: Might I need to use this technique for a `DataGridViewTextBoxCell` ?